# Can I edit a video (change effects) in VLC Media Player?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I changed a video’s effects to negative. Now I want to save the modified video. How can I do this?

I tried to save the file, but the changes did not show up when the file was played in another media player.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open VLC
2. Go to **File > Convert/Save...**
3. Select the media file you want to convert or alter
4. Check **Show more options**
5. In the **Edit Options** field, add your filter options to create the appropriate changes that you desire.
6. Click **Convert/Save**

Note, this will not apply the changes you have selected in the preferences dialog to the file. You will need to look up the command-line format of the effects that you wish to apply. For example, to rotate the video 180 degrees, use

```
:transform-type=180
```

You can find a comprehensive list of the command-line filters [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help), though most are presented in the global format (starting with `--`), which you need to convert to the stream-specific format (which start with `:` instead).

Comment: thanx this is what i needed.

Comment: Is there a way to extract these parameters from the current settings? I can view the video and it looks nice. Do I now have to go to the effects dialog and note down all the individual parameters by hand in order to export it? Also, motion-blur, for example, does not work. It is removed from the settings line and the video is converted without it.

Answer (score 1):

After some thought, I think [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/) is a better tool for this. There is a "Dimensions" tab. You can set the desired cropping for each side, go to the preview tab, and when it looks good, hit "Start Encode". Much easier than figuring out command-line parameters.