# VLC. Rotation works when using command line but it doesn't when entering the options in the Edit Options section

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

If I open command line and type:

```
vlc d:\a.mp4 :vout-filter=transform --transform-type=270 --video-filter "transform{true}"
```

VLC will play with image rotated.

However if I open VLC and type those options here:
[image]

Then the video starts without the rotation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does Preferences > Advanced > Video > Filters > Rotate and pick the rotation angle you want work?

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding goes, The "Edit Options" field can only add parameters
to the filter.

The format of this field is ":option1=value1 :option2=value2" etc.

However, there does not seem to exist any formal documentation of this field,
so this is based on examples I have found.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I had also tried by entering the parameters in that format, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Please add this version of your parameters to your post. One [link](https://superuser.com/a/663879/8672) shows that ":vout-f‌ilter=transform" may not be needed.